# OpenGl And Flickering

Tags: opengl

When objects from a CallList intersect the near plane I get a flicker..., what can I do?

Im using OpenGL and SDL.

Yes it is double buffered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting z-fighting.

"Z-fighting is a phenomenon in 3D rendering that occurs when two or more primitives have similar values in the z-buffer, and is particularly prevalent with coplanar polygons. The effect causes pseudo-random pixels to be rendered with the color of one polygon or another in a non-deterministic manner, varying as the scene is animated, causing one polygon to "win" the z test, then another, and so on."
(From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting))

You can get more information about the problem in the [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm).

glPolygonOffset might help, but you can also get yourself into trouble with it. Tom Forsyth has a good explanation in his [FAQ](http://tomsdxfaq.blogspot.com/2002_07_01_archive.html#79344425#79344425) Note: It talks about ZBIAS, but that's just the DirectX equivilent.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that my rotation function had some floating point errors which screwed up my model_view matrix.

None of you could have guessed it, sorry for the waste of your time.

Although I don't think that moving the near plane should be even considered a solution to any kind of problem usually something else is wrong, because openGL does support polygon intersection with the near plane.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the near clipping plane a little bit further :
for example with gluPerspective -> third parameter **zNear**
http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/glu/perspective.html

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you meant the *near* plane. :)

Well...another thing when drawing polygons in the same plane is to use [glPolygonOffset](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~haoz/teaching/htmlman/polygonoffset.html)

From the description

```
  glPolygonOffset is useful for rendering hidden-line images,
  for applying decals to surfaces, and for rendering solids
  with highlighted edges.
```